# Possible to share Model Derivative URN across apps?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

is it possible to share URNs that is accessible by other apps (a separate set of clientid and clientsecret from the one that was used to upload and translate the file), similar to what viewer.autodesk.com does?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Sorry i gave incorrect answer earlier, yes it's possible, you can refer this [body structure](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-POST/#body-structure-200) in documentation